# How to filter multivalued field from solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj

How to filter field of multivalued type using **fl** ? 
Lets say i have a field:

```
"features_|sub-models|": ["Impala Sedan"]
```

The following **fl** expression doesn't work: `field('features_|sub-models|')`

Comment: when you mentioned 'filter', did you mean fq param (filter query)? If you can you give an example of what you want to achieve with with input and output that you are expecting, it will certainly help

Comment: And both | and - are recommended to keep out of field names, as at least - have special meaning in the query syntax. They're known to give troubles with certain queries.

Comment: @Ganesh, i meant to use "fl" - Fields to Return. I am doing this because document has many data inside it and this improves performance during fetching of big number of documents